How would I update multiple rows in a new foreign key column in an existing table, all with different values?
I have created a database with multiple tables. One table is for products and another is for instructions which go with each product. In the tables, I want to be able to link the two. I've created foreign keys and populated both with information. But of course, I've realised I had to create the foreign key column in one only after completing the other table first. Now, I've created that column, and want to insert values (the instruction_id from the other table) into the products table. Is there a quick way to do this? I am new to SQL.
All I can find, is that I would need to enter:
UPDATE table_name
SET table_name.col1 = new_value
WHERE table_name.col2 = value;

But that would mean repeating this multiple times for each row. It also might not take into account that it is a foreign key. Is there a quicker way to do this, or even a completely different way since it's a foreign key?
Thanks in advance!
Instructions table data Instructions table How I added the foreign key for my models table My models table, without the added instruction_id needed
So as you can (hopefully) see, I have managed to add the model_id to my instructions table. But now, I want to add the instruction_id to the model table, but is there an efficient way to enter the values, rather than the way I have done?

You've not tagged the database you're using, nor have you posted your schema, so it's difficult to be definitive. However, there's nothing magic about foreign keys. They're just an instruction to the database to help maintain data integrity. If you've created tables that should be linked but you haven't provided that data that links them then the only route forward is to provide that data. If you have big tables then it might take ages. We might be able to find a work around from the original source data, but you haven't posted any for us to look at.

Short answer would be no. You need to run that SQL query to update each value.

Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text, appropriately formatted - so that people can copy it

And tag your rdbms

You already have a link between the instructions table and the models table in the model_id column. You can use that to JOIN the two tables and apply the instruction_id as needed:
update instructions join models on (instructions.model_id = models.model_id)
  set models.instruction_id = instructions.instruction_id;


However, this assumes that each model has exactly one set of instructions and vice versa. That being the case, do you need a separate table for instructions?
A more flexible solution would be to create a many-to-many relationship with a dedicated table. See this question for examples.
It's difficult to see how that would be useful for what appears to be Lego kits.
